# Check if there's OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl, exists

I'm trying to check if there's OpenGL on PC with C#, but didn't found any simple solution for now. I'm looking the simplest and the best way to do that, something like:

```
if ( exists_OpenGL ) MessageBox.Show( "yeah, go do your stuff..." );
```

So please, can anyone help me with a code which would be fast and simply enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most operating systems you'll find the API library. This however tells you nothing about the actual OpenGL capabilities. The only way to check for what's available is to create a minimal OpenGL context and query its properties (version, renderer, available extensions).

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a context with a C# OpenGL library such as [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/). This might also give you the version number if it succeeds.

I'm pretty sure most OSs come with some form of OpenGL, so just checking if it exists might not work without knowing the capability too (look how much trouble chrome went to attempting this with webgl, using a list of compatible graphics cards). An alternative, which doesn't seem that stable, might be [directly loading the native DLL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86c9aeff-4db2-4eb0-aff9-11e5e570cf8f/catch-dllimport-exception-on-missing-dll), and maybe even querying it.

Comment: Loading the DLL tells you nothing about HW acceleration capability.